# Cleanly overwrite last output as displayed on the terminal in Bash loop

Tags: bash

I have the following loop to view changing dir size:

```
while true; do du -hcs . ; sleep 2 ; clear ; done
```

What I'm not happy with is the waiting time between the clear and the actual output of `du`. The result is more or less a blinking number.

How can I modify this to simply write the new number over the old, with no black screen in between?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
watch du -hcs .
```

From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/watch):

> **watch** runs *command* repeatedly, displaying its output (the first screenfull). This allows you to watch the program output change over time. By default, the program is run every 2 seconds; use `-n` or `--interval` to specify a different interval.

`watch` is smart: it only redraws the parts of the screen that have changed, avoiding the full screen clears that cause the blinking you see with `clear`.

Comment: `watch` is Linux only. Not on BSD

Answer (score 0):

I think that `watch` is the correct tool for what you are looking for, but

```
while true;do echo -n $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) $(du -hcs ..|grep -v total);sleep 1;echo -e "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b";done
```

might be just the poor substitute that you are looking for.

If, however your shell is dash rather than bash, then use:

```
while true;do echo $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) $(du -hcs ..|grep -v total)|tr -d '\n';sleep 1;echo $'\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b';done
```

Comment: I just ran this, but it doesn't overwrite the last line on my Ubuntu 16.04 system.

Comment: Is it possible that you are running inside of dash rather than bash? `echo $0` to check.

Comment: It says "bash".

Comment: The command you added does the same, they print the output neatly on a new line each time.

Comment: Does the dash version work? or `while true;do echo $(du -hcs ..|grep -v total)|tr -d '\n';sleep 1;echo $'\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b';done` ?

Comment: No .. also prints a new line each time. I'll try the solutions on a 18.04 system now. Edit: same result.